# matplotlib style library not updating when .mplstyle files added/deleted

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-import

I'm trying to create my own matplotlib stylesheets but Python doesn't detect them. Even worse: when I moved one of the five default stylesheets (ggplot.mplstyle), Python kept reporting it was availabe.

I tried to reload the entire module but to no avail:

```
import matplotlib
reload(matplotlib)
from matplotlib import style as style
plt = matplotlib.pyplot
print plt.style.available
```

just keeps returning

```
[u'dark_background', u'bmh', u'grayscale', u'ggplot', u'fivethirtyeight']
```

How can I force a "refresh" of these styles?

P.s. I'm not a Python expert.

Comment: Looks like `plt.style.reload_library()` will do the trick

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Doesnt' throw any error message either, btw.

Comment: Can you report this as a bug then?

Comment: Actually, what happens if you do `matplotlib.style.reload_library()` and then `matplotlib.style.available` ?

Comment: @tcaswell: still no luck. I'll report it as a bug as you suggested.

Answer (score 10):

Just in case someone else stumbles on this post, this issue was reported and resolved here:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3601

Basically, the style library looks for files in a subdirectory of the matplotlib config directory. On linux/osx system, this would be something like `~/.matplotlib/stylelib/<my-custom-style>.mplstyle`.

Also, as @tcaswell suggested in comments, loading is done at import time, so style files added or edited after import will not work without a call to `plt.style.reload_library()`.